# Restricting HTTPS for Tomcat Deployment manager

Tags: ssl, tomcat, https, deployment, tomcat6

As a PCI requirement, I wanted to get the tomcat deployment manager on HTTPS as the password was flowing in plain-text.

I tried few resources like [this](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html).

My current connector is as given below:

```
<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol" executor="tomcatThreadPool"  port="8301" address="0.0.0.0"
        tomcatAuthentication="false" redirectPort="443" proxyPort="443" connectionTimeout="1000" keepAliveTimeout="300000" packetSize="21000" maxHttpHeaderSize="3600000" />
```

and I can access the manager on given port successfully.

I changed the `security-contraint` to enable `HTTPS` by adding the below.

```
<security-constraint>
     <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected Context</web-resource-name>
          <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <!-- auth-constraint goes here if you requre authentication -->
      <user-data-constraint>
         <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
      </user-data-constraint>
   </security-constraint>
```

Please point out if I am missing anything. Any blog or documentation of some sort will help as well.